# Trying to get my WordPress theme to appear full-screen after it stopped working

Tags: css, wordpress

I was editing my site and it stopped displaying full-screen pages. I went to change the top-bar settings and when the page was refreshed, margins were added.

I've researched the theme, Gutenberg/WordPress itself, and tried a lot of recommendations for code fixes.

I went into the theme and reset all of the defaults for the theme.

Disabled all of the plugins.

Tried code that I thought would work and didn't.

Edited the padding in Inspector and got it to work... added the following code to the custom CSS area of the theme and it doesn't work.

```
.wf-wrap {
padding: 0 !important;
}
```

I expected for the site to be full-width. There should be no white left and right sections next to the content.

Comment: Could you post a link to the live website for us to review? This helps us better assist you with your problem.

Comment: Sure, http://ash-creates.com

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A setting 
I tried before now works...maybe it was some sort of Cache issue.